# I can't catch php exceptions using try....catch

Tags: zend-framework, exception, php

I'm having a problem with PHP Exceptions. Even if I try to execute this code:

```
try {
    $some->knownMethodWithError();
} catch(Zend_Exception $exp){
    echo 'Error!: ' . $exp->getMessage();
}
```

My apache/php served web page always display a 500 Error. I mean,

```
echo 'Error!: ' . $exp->getMessage();
```

never is executed. I've tested with a redirection instead of that echo, but it doesn't work. Is there some php.ini directive that cause this behavior, or could it be something else?.

This happens in my Zend Framework based project.

Comment: There are no directives that cause exceptions not to be thrown/caught, but there might be another problem that causes the 500. Check the error logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 500 error isn't a PHP exception, it's happening above the code level. A 500 error means that there was an error while PHP was trying to parse your script (probably). Possibly your code has a syntax error.

Comment: Ok, that could be a good reason, but I've checked the code and there's no syntax error.

Comment: Ok, I was using a third party Soap library that caused that error. This error was killing my application whenever it is generated.

Answer (score 5):

Also, your code will only catch Zend_Exception.
If you have custom Exceptions maybe catch(Exception $e) will get more chances to catch all of them

maybe you could run the script with full logs. Change your `php.ini` on the server on the line :

```
error_reporting=E_ALL | E_STRICT
```

or better run it on an IDE environment with a debugger.

Comment: To catch all the exceptions try `Exception $e` as lenzai said

Comment: Well, in fact this happens not only for Zend_Exception, but for any Exception. In example, if I use SoapClient's __soapCall function, and for some reason it throws a SoapFault exception, I can't catch it. I've checked that code, and there's no sintax error. Even if I use that try...catch block, at least with Firebug, the response has a 500 error code.